# WebRTC how to set constraints to use audio when available

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Typically you would set constraints as follow

```
{ audio: true, video: true }
```

but I'd like to be more permissive then that. I'd like to only get the audio, if it is able to get it *i.e. if a microphone is available*, otherwise it will throw me a `NotFoundError` error.

Any ideas if that's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the [`MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) method to get the list of all audio and video devices. 
This will return an Array of [MediaDeviceInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo) objects which will have a `kind` property letting you know which constraint you can use.

So you could do something like

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(getDevicesTypes)
  .then(getUserMedia)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
  
function getDevicesTypes(list){
  return new Set(list
    .filter(device => device.kind.indexOf('input') > -1)
    .map(device => device.kind.replace('input', ''))
  );
}
function getUserMedia(deviceKinds){
  const constraint = {};
  deviceKinds.forEach(kind => constraint[kind] = true);
  console.log(constraint);
  return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint);
}
```